# Giving one file multiple inode values

Tags: symlink, inode

Is it possible to create a "file" that, essentially, is symlinked to multiple other files.

Let's say we have a /tmp/dir/ with 100 files in it.  What I want is to be able to do is "cat /tmp/dir_allfiles" which would, in essence, be the same as `cat /tmp/*`

The real use case is more complicated where files may be at different directory levels, etc. so please don't suggest I just use `find` or `cat */*/*` or something similar.

I'm fine if I have to use C to do ridiculous / dangerous things.  I'm mostly interested in if it's possible.

Here's some of my uname -a if you are curious `3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is definitely possible to do at the VFS level, e.g. using [FUSE](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse).

In particular, [concat-fuse](https://github.com/concat-fuse/concat-fuse), looks pretty much like what you need:

> concat-fuse is a FUSE based virtual filesystem for Linux that allows handling a collection of files as if they were a single one. It is essentially doing:
>
> cat *.txt > large_file
>
> But instead of creating large_file, it creates a virtual file and accesses the original *.txt files instead.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do something similar in a subshell?

`cat <( cat */foo/*; cat */bar/*/baz; )`

`find` is phenomenally powerful, please explain a little more detail about what you're trying to accomplish as there may be a much more simple answer.

Comment: Mostly I am curious if it's simple possible to have a single file descriptor point to multiple other files.  I realize that sub shells or find or any other approach is "better" or "correct" or "would work".